# Is there a better way to get hold of a reference to a movie clip in actionscript using a string without eval

Tags: actionscript

I have created a bunch of movie clips which all have similar names and then after some other event I have built up a string like:

```
var clipName = "barLeft42"
```

which is held inside another movie clip called 'thing'.

I have been able to get hold of a reference using:

```
var movieClip = Eval( "_root.thing." + clipName )
```

But that feels bad - is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Movie clips are collections in actionscript (like most and similar to javascript, everything is basically key-value pairs). You can index into the collection using square brackets and a string for the key name like:

```
_root.thing[ "barLeft42" ]
```

That should do the trick for you...

Answer (score 0):

The better way, which avoids using the deprecated `eval`, is to index with square brackets:

```
var movieClip = _root.thing[ "barLeft42" ]
```

But the best way is to keep references to the clips you make, and access them by reference, rather than by name:

```
var movieClipArray = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<45; i++) {
    var mc = _root.thing.createEmptyMovieClip( "barLeft"+i, i );
    // ...
    movieClipArray.push( mc );
}

// ...

var movieClip = movieClipArray[ 42 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use brackets and include variables within them... so if you wanted to loop through them all you can do this:

```
for (var i=0; i<99; i++) {
  var clipName = _root.thing["barLeft"+i];
}
```